# C++ can't identify command in DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mdm, zinc

I am trying to make this DLL functionable but can't get it to work even from a ready code.

I create a simple DLL from visual studio in c++ (win32 project)
and I have this 2 files that I use.

headerZincSDK.h

```
// headerZincSDK.h
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#if defined( WIN32 )
#include <tchar.h>
#define mdmT( x )   _T( x )
#else
#define mdmT( x )   L ## x
#endif

extern void OnEntry();

extern bool RegisterModule( const std::wstring& strName );

typedef struct
{
    int formId;
} 
ZincCallInfo_t;

typedef std::wstring ( *ZINC_COMMAND_CALLBACK )( const ZincCallInfo_t& info, const std::vector< std::wstring >& );

extern bool RegisterCommand( const std::wstring& strModuleName,
                     const std::wstring& strCommandName,
                     ZINC_COMMAND_CALLBACK callback );

// Helper commands for returning values
std::wstring AsString( const std::wstring& str );
std::wstring AsInteger( int value );
std::wstring AsBoolean( bool value );
```

And the Main Project.cpp

```
// Project1.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "headerZincSDK.h"

using namespace std;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}

void OnEntry()
 {
     wstring moduleName = mdmT( "TestExt" );

     RegisterModule( moduleName );

     RegisterCommand( moduleName, mdmT( "random" ), Command1 );

     RegisterCommand( moduleName, mdmT( "reverse" ), Command2 );
 } 

wstring Command1 (const ZincCallInfo_t& info, const vector< wstring >& vParams )
 {
     //My Code
 }

wstring Command2 (const ZincCallInfo_t& info, const vector< wstring >& vParams )
 {
     //My Code
 }
```

The problem is that it doesn't build the solution cause it says the Command1 and Command2 are undefined

I have none to nothing knowledge on c++ and these are my first steps but I can understand much and easy.

Can anyone tell me what shall I change in these to two files to make it work?

Comment: Read up on  `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)`

Comment: I don`t think it has something to do with import or export it is a step by step configuration i read and made but it doesnt work. It has to do maby with std the declaration of commands that doesnt recognize i will make the code in few lines just in case

Comment: I'm not an epxert on C++ dlls, but shouldn't your command1 and command2 functions be declared before being used? so move those 2 functions above OnEntry() and try again.

Comment: i have made that change too but gets me some weird errors...The 2 Commands wstring are declared if i am not wrong in the .h file with the typedef std::wstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions `Command1` and `Command2` are not declared in header file with that `typedef` statement. That statement defines a type `ZINC_COMMAND_CALLBACK`, which is a pointer to a function whose signature matches that of functions `Command1` and `Command2`. This means that you can take the address of one of those functions (or any others function with the same signature) and assign it to this pointer:

```
ZINC_COMMAND_CALLBACK comm1 = &Command1;
```

The problem with your code is that you are using these functions before you have declared them. Either put entire definitions for `Command1` and `Command2` before function `OnEntry`, or leave definitions where they are and add the following declarations before `OnEntry`:

```
wstring Command1(const ZincCallInfo_t& info, const vector< wstring >& vParams);
wstring Command2(const ZincCallInfo_t& info, const vector< wstring >& vParams);
```

I have tested this code and it fixes errors related to `Command1` and `Command2`.  New errors that appear are two linker errors caused by the fact that functions `RegisterModule` and `RegisterCommand` are not defined, but I am guessing that you omitted these definitions because they were not relevant to the question.

Comment: i will give it a try and let you know, as i said i followed a guide to create this code, i dont know how the hole thing works in c++ either total newbie on this language but i understand cause of use of other languages.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It worked but only with std infront of them

```
std::wstring Command1 (const ZincCallInfo_t& info, const vector< std::wstring >& vParams )
 {
     //My Code
 }

std::wstring Command2 (const ZincCallInfo_t& info, const vector< std::wstring >& vParams )
 {
     //My Code
 }
```

Otherwise it was full of errors dont know why.
But i manage to enter this std:: infront and it works and yes before the onEntry() function

Thank you all for the quick responses

Comment: Namespace qualification (adding `std::` before type) is only necessary if you have removed the statement `using namespace std;` from "Main Project.cpp".

Comment: Yes indeed, i have removed it that, didnt mention it cause i really dont know all of them what they do and i manage after many tries to achieve it.